# RegEx for matching repeating [01] using capturing groups

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a variable-length string of values (bits actually: 1 and 0, multiples of 32). Eg:

```
010011011001110111100111011010001001100011101100100011100010100011110010100011001111111101101001
```

Each of the 32 bit blocks contains an inner structure: first 8 bits and next 24 bits belong togehter.

I like to

- Fetch each 32 bit block and
- each block's inner structure

in one regex.

My approach

```
^(([01]{8})([01]{24})){0,}$
```

didn't work out since it only matches the last block.

Is such a regex possible? What to look for? What an I doing wrong?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Java, but should not matter, right?

Comment: What do you mean by inner structure? What should be the expected output?

Comment: Use this: '(([01]{8})([01]{24}))' and set the 'global' flag, you will get all matches then.

Comment: Doesn't Java have a findall() function to get these values into an array? You don't have to match everything in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have slightly modified it using [this tool](https://regex101.com/r/hwm3Lq/1):

```
(([0-1]{8})([0-1]{24}))
```

If I understand correctly, you may not want to bound it with start and end chars. You can simply use another capturing group around it and with the other two capturing groups that you already have, extract the data, as you wish.

[image: u]

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) helps you to visualizes your expressions:

[image]

#### JavaScript Testing Demo

```js
const regex = /(([0-1]{8})([0-1]{24}))/gm;
const str = `010011011001110111100111011010001001100011101100100011100010100011110010100011001111111101101001
`;
const subst = `Group #1: $1\nGroup #2: $2\nGroup #3: $3\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Performance Test

This snippet returns the runtime of a 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const regex = /(([0-1]{8})([0-1]{24}))/gm;
 const str = `010011011001110111100111011010001001100011101100100011100010100011110010100011001111111101101001`;
 const subst = `\nGroup #1: $1\nGroup #2: $2\nGroup #3: $3`;

 var match = str.replace(regex, subst);
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: `[0-1]` and `[01]` are the same thing in ASCII-based encodings.

Comment: This worked! Why didn't it work with my extension of `...{0,}`?

Comment: Are you using `matcher.find()` ?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help! I will look into this more deeply.

Answer (score 1):

In java, you can get one match at a time.

#### Code

```java
// \G matches only exactly where the previous `find()` left off
// (?:^|\G) matches either at start of line or where previous `find()` left off
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^|\G)([01]{8})([01]{24})");
// inputString should not contain e.g. newline characters
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
boolean lastMatchEnd = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    String firstPart = m.group(1);
    String secondPart = m.group(2);
    // ...
    // remember how far we got
    lastMatchEnd = m.end();
}
if (lastMatchEnd != inputString.length()) {
  // if we get here, there were garbage in the line that did not match
}
```